# Salesforce Data Loader bulk api result files

Tags: data-loader

I see that when I run the Salesforce Dataloader with the bulk api mode enabled it still produces result files containing the success and error records. I did not expect this since the Bulk API is asynchronous.

Does this mean that the Salesforce Dataloader is pulling the job status frequently from Salesforce and download the files when the job is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any tool using the [Bulk api](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/api_asynch.pdf) will open a job, submit one or more batches, check the status of the batches, close the job, and download the results.

The successes and errors for a batch come back in one file though based on the order they were submitted. The dataloader must separate them out afterwards.